# Eclipse Android Project Classes Not Visible from Included Project. Nothing works

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a project A which depends on Project B.
I have added it as project but the classes in Project B are not visible no matter what I do. There are 100's of errors.  Sometimes for a while I would open close Project A and it would then work. Now nothing works. Not even putting the jar file generated by Project B in A's list of libraries.  It just refuses to see and ack these classes. Do I need to reinstall eclipse?

Lots of Cannot Be Resolved to a type errors.  Basically I cannot see anything in Project B from A so lots of not found exceptions. Always quirky now no classes from B are being seen even with open close of A.

Comment: Just to make sure: Refresh both projects, Project clean both projects. If that does not help, try closing and reopening eclipse. That sometimes helps.

Comment: another problem is I cannot remove the added library jar.  It is grayed out ...

Comment: its included as Android Dependency but I cannot find any option to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean both/rebuild projects, to refresh the dependencies